# How can I get and post the data via a Blazor App?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I want to make an App for a custom service chat using server-side of Blazor.

It has less than 10 active users per-day.

The user side is not made by us and only the customer-service side will make by Blazor.

So when the user side posts a message, the customer-service side needs to get it and render it in the front-end immediately.

When the customer-service side inputs a message, it needs to post to the remote-server immediately also.

I have learned about how to post and get via the asp.net core yet. Whereas, it seems I can't add an `IActionResult` in the `code` block of Blazor. I think if I can add it to the `code` block, maybe I can bind the model and then transfer the `IActionResult` of get/post to the model.

I searched google about this and most of them are about the CRUD while I don't need a database at all.

Would you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: I found the source codes of a Blazor chat app yet. However, all of the data send/get results are get from the javascript. I want to know whether I achieve it by the code only with .net?